# htaccess problem after adding trailing slash

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

After being looking for a while about how to add trailing slashes to my routes by htaccess I thought the job was done.

Everything looked fine, but sadly, if I try to login with my route mysite.com/login/, it redirect itself (to mysite.com/login/ again) and it does not allow to login.

These are the lines that "work" at adding trailing slash:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

If I remove these lines, you can login with no problem, but the trailing slashes at my routes dissapear.

What should I edit to get trailing slashes and get my login working?

Comment: "but the trailing slashes at my routes dissapear" - Are you suggesting that _something else_ is actually removing the trailing slash when a trailing slash is included on the requested URL? If so then you need to resolve that first before attempting to implement something else. And to clarify, the redirect in `.htaccess` is not a substitute for including the trailing a slash on all your internal links, if that is what you are thinking?

Comment: I meant if i remove these lines of course the slashes are gone. Those lines are for adding / after my links/routes automatically. In my projec, routes with / works perfectly. We are talking about a redirection problem: My goal is to redirect mysite.com/es to mysite.com/es/

Comment: "I meant if i remove these lines of course the slashes are gone." - those lines should not be integral to your site. If you intend to have trailing slashes on your URLs then your site should already be including the trailing slash on all internal URLs. Those directives in `.htaccess` are only to canonicalise the request should a third party link to the non-canicalise, ie. slashless URL. You need to make your site work with URLs that include a trailing slash. The solution to this would seem to be in your Laravel project, not `.htaccess`.